Centering a PushButton directly beneath a Label in PyQt6
I'm trying to get the button to be centered beneath the label using PyQt6. I would also like it to work when resizing the window. Thank you in advance!
layout = QVBoxLayout()

self.welcome_label = QLabel("Welcome to Application!", self)
self.welcome_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
self.welcome_label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 30))
layout.addWidget(self.welcome_label)

self.start_button = QPushButton('Start')
self.start_button.setFixedSize(QSize(100,30))
layout.addWidget(self.start_button)

self.setLayout(layout)

Current look and arrow to where I would like the button to go:

I have tried adding spacers, deleting margins, using screen size information to change geometry location but have had no luck.

This will do it without any sub-layouts:
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)

        welcome_label = QLabel("Welcome to Application!")
        welcome_label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 30))

        start_button = QPushButton('Start')
            
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(welcome_label, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(start_button, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        layout.addStretch()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

You use addStretch() twice to centre the label and button vertically and keep them together.
You use addWidget() with the alignment argument to centre the widgets horizontally.
AlignCenter also makes sure that the button doesn't expand horizontally to the full width of the widget.

There's no need to set the size-policy on the button (and in any case, setting Maximum, Maximum makes no sense). The default is Minimum, Fixed, so using AlignHCenter is sufficient.

@ekhumoro, Yes you're right. I used AlignVCenter first and didn't check if the sizepolicy was still needed when I switched to AlighCenter. Answer edited. thanks

You've got the right idea at least with using spacers, you just need to learn how to effectively use them.
Currently you have 1 layout with 2 sections:
-------------
|           |
|<  label  >|
|           |
-------------
|<button>   |
-------------

Personally I find that it can be tricky to make the widgets do what you want. As you've found, the label can be aligned, but the button isn't working that way.
Instead of using alignment, it's a lot easier to rely on layouts with stretches. Two stretches either side will centre a widget.
--------------------
|<-->| widget |<-->|
--------------------

To prevent the label from taking up so much height, add a stretch underneath the button to push everything up.
-----------------
|<label layout >|
-----------------
|<button layout>|
-----------------
|       ^       |
|       v       |

This is the result:
layout = QVBoxLayout()

self.welcome_label = QLabel("Welcome to Application!", self)
self.welcome_label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 30))
welcome_layout = QHBoxLayout()
welcome_layout.addStretch()
welcome_layout.addWidget(self.welcome_label)
welcome_layout.addStretch()
layout.addLayout(welcome_layout)

self.start_button = QPushButton('Start')
self.start_button.setFixedSize(QSize(100,30))
start_layout = QHBoxLayout()
start_layout.addStretch()
start_layout.addWidget(self.start_button)
start_layout.addStretch()
layout.addLayout(start_layout)

layout.addStretch()
self.setLayout(layout)


All layouts will add padding by default, if you need to remove it from around each widget then just use child_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0).

For a situation like this, using sub layouts is unnecessary as the answer from mahkitah shows. Also, "All layouts will add padding by default" is not completely true, because layout margins are undefined by default and are only finally set once a layout is actually set on a widget (then defined by the style if not explicitly set), but nested layouts (layouts that are direct children of another layout) do not normally have any margin.
